# Re-using the code in onNewIntent in fragment

Tags: android

I am converting an activity that has a webview into fragment. I have some code in `onNewIntent()` method of the activity. Since there is no such method in fragment, Which would be the better approach to accomplish the task in `onNewIntent` in `Fragment`.

Thanks

Comment: just use onCreateView()